# verify button is not displayed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried the following solutions to Verify that the button is not displayed for a particular user-group.None of the solutions work. I get a no such element exception with the  codes.
Please let me know if there is anything else i can try.

```
  try {
                    boolean btnPresence = driver.findElement(By.linkText("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button")).isDisplayed();

                }
           catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e)
                {
                            return;
                }
                }
                Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button")).isDisplayed());
                if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button")).isDisplayed()) {
                    System.out.println("Fail! Submit button is displayed for a CMS Admin on the ORC TA Form.");}
                else {
                        System.out.println("Pass!!- Submit Button is not displayed for CMS Admin on the ORC TA Form");
                     }   

                boolean elePresent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button")).isDisplayed();
                boolean elePresent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button")).isDisplayed();
                boolean exist = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/button")).size() == 0;
```

Comment: Please format your code properly (remove the comments) and consider adding a [mcve] for us to test.

Comment: After doing what Zephyr suggested, please describe what happens when you execute the code.

Comment: When the button isn't displayed, does it exist in the DOM and is just not visible or is it not in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element exists or not:

```
public boolean existsElement_byXpath(String xpath) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```